# How to filter rows with pandas without using the column name - loop filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter rows in a DataFrame using Pandas but instead of using:

```
df[(df.ColumnA == 1)]
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
i = 'A'
x = 'Column'+'i'
df[(df.x == 1)]
```

My aim is to loop in the columns filters.
It would be even better if I could do this:

```
i = A
x = 'Column'+'i'
y = 1
df[(df.x == y)]
```

Allowing me to loop in the columns and loop in the filter types:

Thanks!

Comment: The `pandas` way actively shuns looping in favor of proper indexing and selecting due to the expensive overhead incurred in looping. Are you sure you cannot apply indexing plus, for example, a lambda expression to apply these filters?

Comment: What you're saying can be done but it doesn't make sense, it sounds like you just want some user defined func that takes a column name and value to perform the filtering, can you explain more. Also your codesn't make much sense if `i = A` then `x = 'Column' + 'i'` will produce a string `'Columni'` rather than `'ColumnA'` which would be just `x = 'Column' + i`

Comment: @Metatron: Thanks for the information I looked for lambda and saw that it also csolves my problem!

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks for the correction, you got it right!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to grab a Series from DataFrame, but having trouble because the `.` notation won't allow a variable, you could use brackets instead:

```
i = 'A'
column = 'Column' + i
df = df[df[column] == 1]
```

You could also create a mask in a loop and apply it all at once:

```
column_base = 'Column'
suffixes = ['A','B','C','D']
mask = None

for i in suffixes:
    column = column_base + i
    if mask is None:
        mask = df[column] == 1
    else:
        mask &= df[column] == 1

df = df[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer you solved my problem really clear!
I will use the brackets option for now.